# jQuery UI Multiple Tab Containers with Sortables

Tags: jquery, tabs, sortables

I'm having a difficult time accomplishing something with jQuery.  I have multiple tab containers.  Inside each tab container, there are multiple tabs.  Inside each of these tabs, there is a sortable.  The sortables contain portlets.  I'm trying to drag these portlets from one sortable in one tab in one tab container, to another sortable in another tab in another tab container.  Confused?

Here's a jsFiddle that shows what I'm trying to accomplish: http://jsfiddle.net/ZLGWF/

```
<snip>
```

The problem is that sometimes the sortable that I'm dragging to won't recognize the portlet until I've dragged it halfway through the sortable.  Sometimes it won't recognize it at all.

Any idea what I'm doing incorrectly?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

**tolerance** *Default: "intersect"*

Specifies which mode to use for testing whether the item being moved is hovering over another item. Possible values:

- "intersect": The item overlaps the other item by at least 50%.
- "pointer": The mouse pointer overlaps the other item.

So the "problem" you describe is jQuery sortable's default behavior. You've set the option "tolerance" to "touch", which actually isn't valid, causing the plugin to go with its default of "intersect" instead.

I've tested your fiddle and cannot reproduce that the dragged sortable sometimes isn't recognized at all.

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to mention that I've tested with every kind of tolerance, on both the sortables and the droppables.


I've updated the jsFiddle to use tolerance of "pointer" on all of the sortables.  Now, try dragging the issue from "Closed Issues" to "Pending Issues".  It doesn't recognize the issue(or, at very least, doesn't show the placeholder) until the cursor is almost on the right edge of the containing tab.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZLGWF/3/

Comment: What browser are you using?